# iTunes connect preview video disappear after certain time

Tags: ios, xcode, video, app-store-connect

I can upload,play and save preview video in iTunes connect. But after certain time the video disappear. No error message or anything. Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs processing time before submitting review.

Comment: It is showing processing but after some time it's vanished. The app already approved by Apple but no preview video is there. In my previous app video was good.